# Text input becomes unusable after submitting data

Tags: react-native, submit, user-input

I am implementing a page in my app that takes a user input and then searches a tv shows API for shows relating to what the user inputs. The form works, and data is returned succesfully, however once the search button has been clicked and the data has been returned, the search bar AND search button becomes unresponsive and will not bring up the keyboard. This was tested on a pixel 3 AVD, however on an iphone X using expo Go, the search button fully disapears from the page!

Here is the code:

```react
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Image } from 'react-native';
import {AntDesign} from '@expo/vector-icons';



const ShowDisplay = ({navigation}) => {

  const[text, changeText] = useState('');
  const[data, setData] = useState([]);


  const check = (item) => {
    if(item.show.image){
      return(
        <Image source={{uri:item.show.image.medium}} style={{width:'100%', height: 200}} />
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <Text>Poo</Text>
      )
    }
  }
  

 const showfind = () =>{
  fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=' + text)
  .then((response)=> response.json())
  .then((json)=> setData(json))
  .catch((error)=>alert(error));
 }

const showSearch = (text) =>{
  showfind();
}


const changeHandler = (text) =>{
 changeText(text)
}

console.log('text is currently '+ text)


 return( 
  <>
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style = {styles.searchform}>
    <TextInput 
      placeholder = 'Search for a show'
       style = {styles.search}
       onChangeText={text => changeHandler(text)}
  />
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showSearch(text)}>
    <AntDesign name="search1" size={30} color='black' style = {{marginTop: 19, marginLeft: 15,}}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</View>

<View>
  {data? (<View style={styles.resultsContainer}>
<FlatList
style = {styles.list}
keyExtractor={(item, index)=> index.toString()}
  numColumns= '3'
  data={data}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <>
    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.show} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('toShow', {
     id: item.show.id,

    } )}>    
  
    <View style={styles.text}>
    {check(item)}
     </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
   

</>
  )}
  
  />
</View>) : (<View style={styles.loadingContainer}>

<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#000"/>

</View>)}


</View>




</>

);

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',


},
search :{
  paddingLeft: 15,
  marginTop: 20,
  borderRadius:30,
  width: 200,
  height: 30,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#000'
}, header : {
  marginTop: 20,
  fontSize: 30,
},
searchform:{
flexDirection: 'row',
},

show:{
  width: '33.3%',
  height: 200,
  borderStyle: "solid",
  borderColor: 'white',
  borderWidth: 1,
}, 
list:{
 marginTop: 70,
 
}

});

  
  export default ShowDisplay;
```

I thought that maybe because the sumbit button runs a function, maybe the function never stops, and needs to be reset? When the sumbit button is pressed, it makes the call to the API.. I am unsure what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a weird side effect by using a Fragment (`<></>`) as the root view. The style is getting thrown off in certain circumstances.

Since you don't actually have a reason to use a Fragment as the root (your `container` view is the root element), removing it seemed to solve the issue. I also removed the unnecessary fragment you were using in the search button.

```
return( 
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style = {styles.searchform}>
    <TextInput 
      placeholder = 'Search for a show'
       style = {styles.search}
       onChangeText={text => changeHandler(text)}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showSearch(text)}>
     <AntDesign name="search1" size={30} color='black' style = {{marginTop: 19, marginLeft: 15,}}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

  <View>
   {data? (<View style={styles.resultsContainer}>
      <FlatList
          style = {styles.list}
          keyExtractor={(item, index)=> index.toString()}
          numColumns= '3'
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
             <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.show} onPress={() =>          
                  navigation.navigate('toShow', {
                    id: item.show.id,
                  } )}>    
  
              <View style={styles.text}>
                {check(item)}
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
  
      />
      </View>) : (<View style={styles.loadingContainer}>

      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#000"/>

    </View>)}
  </View>
</View>
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I will be careful in using fragments in the future, I was using them for wrapping everything... I guess it's not the best practise!

Comment: Probably best to use them only when you're trying to avoid a situation where you would otherwise have multiple root nodes. If you just have one, stick with returning the element itself and no fragment wrapper.